# Provable coherence in OTT

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-theory, observational-type-theory

I'm playing with [observational type theory](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/obseqnow.pdf).

Here is equality of `π`-types (`π` is the lowercase `Π`, i.e. `π A B` is the code for `(x : A) -> B x`) defined mutually with coercions:

```
π A₁ B₁ ≃ π A₂ B₂ = σ (A₂ ≃ A₁) λ P -> π _ λ x -> B₁ (coerce P x) ≃ B₂ x
```

and equality of functions defined accordingly (`σ` is the lowercase `Σ`):

```
_≅_ {A = π A₁ B₁} {π A₂ B₂} f₁ f₂ = σ (A₂ ≃ A₁) λ P -> π _ λ x -> f₁ (coerce P x) ≅ f₂ x
```

So instead of "equal functions map equal inputs to equal outputs" we have "equal functions map definitionally equal inputs to equal outputs".

In this setting `coherence`

```
coerce : ∀ {α β} {A : Univ α} {B : Univ β} -> ⟦ A ≃ B ⟧ᵀ -> ⟦ A ⟧ᵀ -> ⟦ B ⟧ᵀ
coherence : ∀ {α β} {A : Univ α} {B : Univ β}
          -> (P : ⟦ A ≃ B ⟧ᵀ) -> (x : ⟦ A ⟧ᵀ) -> ⟦ x ≅ coerce P x ⟧ᵀ
```

(`Univ 0` is `Prop`, `Univ (suc α)` is `Type α`)

is provable. The only thing I needed to postulate is

```
postulate ≃-refl : ∀ {α} -> (A : Univ α) -> ⟦ A ≃ A ⟧ᵀ
```

But we can tweak equality to handle `A ≃ A` as a special case (I think, `trustMe` needs a friend `_≟_ : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} (x y : A) -> Maybe (x ≡ y)`).

We still need to postulate something to define `subst` and other stuff.

Did I miss something? Do we lose any irrelevance? It seems suspicious to mention type equality in the definition of equality of functions. Do we lose much by restricting inputs of equal functions to be definitionally equal? Is there anything good about having strongly normalizing `coherence` or it doesn't matter, since it's computationally irrelevant anyway?

[The code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/Almost.agda) (I ignored positivity, termination and cumulativity issues altogether).

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a better fit for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, I suspect I'll get better answers here. My code is in Agda and OTT's irrelevance is all about programs rather than proofs, so, I think, the question fits for SO too.

Comment: It seems to me that the reason you need to mention type equality in the definition of function equality is that your function equality is heterogenous, i.e. you have `f1 : Π A1 B1` and `f2 : Π A2 B2`, so you first need to "sort out the A1 vs A2 situation" before even thinking about applying both functions on the "same" argument.

Comment: Also, you'd be better off setting `_≟_` to be a total decider, i.e. to return `Dec (x ≡ y)` instead of merely `Maybe (x ≡ y)`.

Comment: @Cactus, I think, it's standard to name codes for types in lowercase. Conor McBride uses the same notation in his [lecture notes](https://github.com/pigworker/SSGEP-DataData/blob/master/notes.pdf) (chapter 4.2). Yes, the equality is heterogeneous, I could add propositional equality to the universe and insist that equal functions have propositionally equal domains, but it's even more restrictive setting and I don't know whether we lose much in the current. `_≟_` would check for definitional equality, it's not possible to write a decidable checker for propositional equality.

Comment: @user3237465 I didn't mean to say that you're wrong to use heterogenous equality there; I was merely answering one of your sub-question about why you need that domain equality there.

Comment: @Cactus, that's my bad wording: I understand why I needed explicit type equality, I don't understand consequences of such situation. I replaced "It seems strange" with "It seems suspicious".

Comment: "I could add propositional equality to the universe and insist that equal functions have propositionally equal domains" — no, I couldn't. I [wrote](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/WithEq.agda) this version and it [inspects](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/WithEq.agda#L119) proofs in a strict way. Though, I'm not sure whether it's safe to lazily replace `p` with `refl / refl` in  `p : ⟦ A ≈ B ⟧` (but we don't have such tool in Agda anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for asking about Observational Type Theory. Secondly, what you've done here *does* seem to hang together, even though it has things in different places from where Thorsten Altenkirch, Wouter Swierstra and I put them in our version of the story. Thirdly, it's no surprise (at least not to me) that coherence is derivable, leaving reflexivity the only postulate. That's true of our OTT as well, and Wouter did the proofs in Agda 1, back when we wrote that paper. Proof irrelevance and the shortness of life meant I didn't port his proofs to Agda 2.

If you've missed anything, it's lurking in your remark

> We still need to postulate something to define `subst` and other stuff.

If you have some `P : X -> Set`, some `a, b : X` and some `q : a = b`, you expect to get a function in `P a -> P b`. The "equal functions take equal inputs to equal outputs" formulation gives you that, as `refl P : P = P`, so from `q`, we can deduce `P a = P b`. Your "equal functions take a given input to equal outputs" formulation does not allow you to let `q` bridge the gap from `a` to `b`.

In the presence of `refl` and `subst`, "two equal inputs" amounts to the same thing as "one input used in two places". It seems to me that you've moved the work into whatever else you need to get `subst`. Depending on how lazy your definition of `coerce` is (and *that*'s how you get proof irrelevance), you will need only a postulate.

With your particular formulation, you might even get away with a *homogeneous* value equality. If you're fixing type gaps with coercions rather than equations, you might save yourself some trouble (and maybe get rid of that equation on the domain type in function equality). Of course, in that case, you'd need to think about how to replace the statement of coherence.

We tried quite hard to keep coercion out of the definition of equality, to retain some sort of symmetry, and to keep type equations out of value equations, mostly to have less to think about at one go. It's interesting to see that at least some parts of the construction might get easier with "a thing and its coercion" replacing "two equal things".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't get this part: "does not allow you to let `q` bridge the gap from `a` to `b`". The definition of `coerce` should be as lazy as possible, as I only use irrefutable matching via `let` and a result of `coerce` doesn't depend computationally on a proof of `⟦ A ≃ B ⟧`. I added [`subst`](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/Almost.agda#L148), is there something wrong with it?

Comment: What does your postulate with the obscured type say? It says that if `a = b` then `P a = P b`. That's to say, your extra postulate (and that's all I said you'd need) allows you to prove type equations from value equations. As long as `coerce` is lazy, it'll work just fine.

Comment: I didn't get that part, because I didn't realize that with equal-to-equal functions you can prove even `subst`. I've [tried](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/OTT/Basic.agda) this and it seems that to finish the job I need either to extend the universe with some universe polymorphism or to prove propositions like `≅-sym` by induction. I couln't even imagine that OTT is that powerful: since it is possible to make everything compute, we can write a proof-relevant version of `coerce` and `subst` will compute even on open terms. Thanks for the elaborations and for OTT.